# Pointing to instance methods from a static table in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I want to have a table sort of like this:

```
static final Record [] table = {
    new Record( Pattern.compile( "regex1" ), MyClass::f1 ),
    new Record( Pattern.compile( "regex2" ), MyClass::f2 )
};
```

where `f1`, `f2` etc are references to instance (not static) methods with an argument and a return value each like this:

```
public int f1( int arg ) {
    return arg * arg;
}
public int f2( int arg ) {
    return arg + arg;
}
```

so I can invoke them something like this (pseudocode):

```
void foo( String s, int arg ) {
    for( Record r : table ) {
        if( r.regex.matcher( s ).matches() ) {
            int result = r.func.invokeOn( this, arg );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way of declaring the second argument of the `Record` constructor, aka member variable `func` in the pseudocode? I figured it out for static `f1`, `f2` etc, but I get a variety of rather incomprehensible error messages regardless what I try for non-static declarations of `f1` etc. I assume it can be done?

Comment: Can you post the constructor of Record? Or at least the type of the second argument?

Comment: You just need an interface with a method of the appropriate type.  Looks like you want [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html).

Comment: In the example you demonstrated, both `f1` and `f2` _can_ be static. You need to show an example of where it wouldn't work and what you expect the inputs of your `Record`-based process to be (e.g., is there an instance of `MyClass` involved somewhere?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BiFunction<MyClass, Integer, Integer>` assuming `MyClass` is the class containing the methods (or use an Interface instead of a class). A method reference to a non-static method without an instance (only the class is given), kind of introduces<sup>1</sup> an additional parameter representing the instance when the method is executed (`this`) as first parameter.

```
class Record {
    BiFunction<MyClass, Integer, Integer> func = MyClass::f1;
}
```

for

```
class MyClass {
    public int f1(int arg) {
        return arg * arg;
    }

    int example(Record r, int arg) {
        return r.func.apply(this, arg);
    }
}
```

---

1 - actually the `this` parameter is already in the bytecode of all instance methods (there is just no need to declare it. The `f1` method is equivalent to `public int f1(MyClass this, int arg)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need those functions to be `static`, or you need to explain where the instance variables will come from. In order to give you a complete example, I had to write `Record`. In short, you want a `Function<Integer, Integer>` and you want to `apply` it. Something like,

```
class Record {
    private Pattern regex;
    private Function<Integer, Integer> func;

    public Record(Pattern p, Function<Integer, Integer> f) {
        this.regex = p;
        this.func = f;
    }

    void foo(String s, int arg) {
        for (Record r : table) { // this.regex.matcher(s).matches() ?
            if (r.regex.matcher(s).matches()) {
                int result = r.func.apply(arg);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    static final Record[] table = {
            new Record(Pattern.compile("regex1"), Record::f1),
            new Record(Pattern.compile("regex2"), Record::f2)
    };

    public static int f1(int arg) {
        return arg * arg;
    }

    public static int f2(int arg) {
        return arg + arg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably not a big deal, but `IntUnaryOperator` would avoid the boxing overhead.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That's a good optimization. But I still don't understand why OP has `table`. This code is giving me an itch.

Comment: It appears OP is trying to implement a command shell, possibly with regex captures for the arguments.

Comment: That part makes perfect sense to me, honestly.  Just matching varying patterns -- possibly more complex than simple constants in future -- to methods.

Comment: It matches file name patterns to parsers. Like `Customers_\\d+.csv` and `Vendors_\\d+.json`.

Comment: @JohannesErnst In the context of `this.regex` being available though. That's the instance variable that makes sense to me. I think the example is just incomplete enough to bother me.